# How to run Linux on PS3?

Tags: linux, playstation

I'm learning numeric computation and have a Core i5, 4gb laptop which I find to be slow for some tasks.

I've read that a single PS3 has the processing power of 30 clustered PCs. And that several PS3 clusters are in use as super computers.

I'm thinking of purchasing a PS and installing Linux on it and then running my python programs on it.

How should I go about creating a personal PS3 super computer? (A cluster of only 1 would be good enough)

Comment: Is your python program parallel ? vectored ? is it even fast ? there is a lot of possible optimization before investing in a strange, heavily parallel architecture on which single-threaded python scripts will most likely run slower.

Comment: Kshitiz, please take a minute to read through our [FAQ] again. With all of your questions closed, you run into danger of being blocked from asking any further questions by the system. If you are unsure of whether something is on-topic here, consider coming to [meta] first, or asking around in [chat]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check properties of your graphics card / processor. It might be quite powerful processing  wise.

If it is CUDA or OpenCL compliant you might already own a very powerful platform.

Some starting points:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA
and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opencl

Also you might consider renting some grid computing or cloud computing capacities. Might be even cheaper. And far less complicated then learning to develop for a new platform.

I am quite a happy European Grid Infrastructure user.

Answer (score 2):

On old PS3 versions Linux can be installed via PS3's own menu, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OtherOS for details. But after some time Sony has disabled this functionality for marketing reasons, so for new consoles installing linux requires some actions to disable PS3 security system, that is illegal in some countries. You can easily google detailed instructions:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbxZEEqJoyg